what is the meaning of parent child relationship in context provider in react
//FatherComponent.jsx

import React from 'react';

import SonComponent from './SonComponent';

import {ThemeProvider} from './ThemeContext';

export default function FatherComponent() {

return (
    <>
    <ThemeProvider> /*Component that provides the two providers*/
        <SonComponent/> /*Previously Children*/
    </ThemeProvider>
    </>
);
}
//SonComponent.jsx

import React from 'react';
import { useTheme, useThemeUpdate } from './ThemeContext';

export default function SonComponent() {

    const darkTheme = useTheme();
    const toggleTheme = useThemeUpdate();
    const themeStyles = {
        backgroundColor: darkTheme ? '#333' : '#CCC',
        color: darkTheme ? '#CCC' : '#333',
        padding: '2rem',
        margin: '2rem'
    }

    return(
        <>
            <button onClick={toggleTheme}>Toggle theme</button>
            <div style={themeStyles}>Hello World</div>
        </>
    )
}

//ThemeContext.jsx

import React , { useContext, useState } from 'react';

const ThemeContext = React.createContext(); /*Context to handle boolean state of 
darkTheme*/
const ThemeUpdateContext = React.createContext(); /*Context to handle the toggling of 
that darkTheme state*/

export function useTheme() {
    return useContext(ThemeContext); /*Creation of custom hook useTheme which exports 
ThemeContext context*/
}

export function useThemeUpdate() {
    return useContext(ThemeUpdateContext); /*Creation of custom hook useThemeUpdate 
which exports ThemeUpdateContext context*/
}

export function ThemeProvider({ children }) { /*Function which exports both context 
providers with children components within it*/

    const [darkTheme, setDarkTheme] = useState(true);

    const toggleTheme = () => {
    setDarkTheme(prevDarkTheme => !prevDarkTheme)
    }

    return(

        <ThemeContext.Provider value={darkTheme}>
            <ThemeUpdateContext.Provider value={toggleTheme}>
                { children }
            </ThemeUpdateContext.Provider>
        </ThemeContext.Provider>
    )
}

in this code ThemeContext is for passing the value of darkTheme and other ThemeUpdateContext is for passing toggle function that toggle the theme. Why are we using both ThemeContext provider and ThemeUpdateContext provider to pass two
different values? why cant we just pass both toggleTheme and darkTheme in ThemeContext
provider only? If i do that the code doesnt work. What is the significance of wrapping our component with two different providers?

You can use a single React Context to provide the darkTheme and toggleTheme values. In fact, I don't really see any point or purpose for splitting const [darkTheme, setDarkTheme] = useState(true); into separate contexts. Typically you'd "bundle" all the state and related updaters/callbacks in a single provided context.

To use only one Context to Provide multiple values to Child components, pass an Array of the values to the Provider such that you may retrieve it as an Array. [1]
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react';


const ThemeContext = createContext();

export function useTheme() {
    return useContext(ThemeContext);
}

export function ThemeProvider({ children }){

    const [darkTheme, setDarkTheme] = useState(true);
    const toggleTheme = () => setDarkTheme(prevDarkTheme => !prevDarkTheme);

    return (
        <ThemeContext.Provider value={[darkTheme, toggleTheme]}>
            { children }
        </ThemeContext.Provider>
    )
}
Now when you receive the values from ThemeContext, you receive an Array.
import { useTheme } from './ThemeContext';


export default function SonComponent() {

    const [darkTheme, toggleTheme] = useTheme();
    
    const themeStyles = {
        backgroundColor: darkTheme ? '#333' : '#CCC',
        color: darkTheme ? '#CCC' : '#333',
        padding: '2rem',
        margin: '2rem'
    }

    return (
        <>
            <button onClick={toggleTheme}>Toggle theme</button>
            <div style={themeStyles}>Hello World</div>
        </>
    )
}
Keep in mind that if any reactive value in the Context changes, the Context re-renders.


What is the meaning of parent-child relationship in context provider in react?

The Parent is the topmost Component in the Component tree and it is the Component that Provides Context. The Child is the first nested Component that receives Context in this tree. The Grand Child is the second nested Component that receives Context in this tree. The Great Grand Child is the…
The code in the OP illustrates this.
import { ThemeProvider as Parent } from './ThemeContext';
import SonComponent from './SonComponent';


export default function Container() {
    return (
        <>
            <Parent>
                <SonComponent/>
            </Parent>
        </>
    )
}
Changes in naming were made for better illustration. These changes are highlighted.

[1] Pass an Object such that you may retrieve an Object. You could even pass a Date instance such that you may retrieve a Date instance.

Objects are valid Context values, there's no requirement to pass an array. Many could validly argue using an array makes working with the context value more difficult since now you need to also destructure all the earlier array elements to get to the one a component actually cares about, i.e. if a component only cared to access the toggleTheme value.

I’ll add that for completeness.
